# Enable Task Tags in Scala IDE for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, comments, scala-ide

Is there a way to enable TODO/FIXME/etc type tasks in the Scala IDE for eclipse?  The only TODO's that I see are for .java files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was discarded by Scala's compiler [until recently](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/4f5159f0ed90598d1e5553afcce7ef2d1ff59d51). If you use a nightly trunk, it ought to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a regression and a ticket for it exists:

http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000634

Comment: This has been fixed today (https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide/pull/35) and it will be available with the next nighlty.